# Plotting vectors with same length

Tags: matlab, plot, linear-algebra

```
function SS(A,b,x)

sum = A*x+b;

xaxis=linspace(-10,10);
ylabel('y')
xlabel('x')

subplot(1,2,1)
plot(xaxis,sum)
axis([0 1 0 1])

subplot(1,2,2)
plot(xaxis,x)
```

I get the error:

> Error using plot Vectors must be the same length.
>
> Error in SS (line 12)
>
> plot(xaxis,sum)

I gave the A matrix a 2x2 and vectors b & x an random 2x1 vector. The way I see, it's the same length.

Answer (score 0):

The error is in `plot()`, not in your input arguments. If it was, Matlab would've thrown the error for the following line

```
sum = A*x+b;
```

and not for the `plot()` line.
The `plot()` help page says that if you do `plot(x,y)` then `x` and `y` must have the same length, that's why the error. If you don't specify any third argument in `linespace()` it will give 100 evenly spaced points between the two arguments you already provided (i.e. upper and lower bounds). Indeed `xaxis` has size 1x100, as instead the variable `sum` has size 2x1.

Now it is worth noticing that:

- it doesn't matter if one is a row-vector whereas the other is a column-vector: the important thing is they have the same size (length)
- it is bad practice to name a variable `sum` because `sum()` is a built-in function in Matlab. Same story goes for any other built-in functions.

Answer (score -1):

The variable xaxis is a 2x100 array, not a 2x1 array.

(see http://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/linspace.html )

You can use the functions length() or size() to work out the size of your arrays. When plotting, us a 1 to 1 mapping, i.e. each value in x has a corresponding value in y.